# Number of ways to divide variables into two categories

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I'm looking for a possible solution to find out the maximum number of combinations that can be derived from the given variables. If I'm not mistaken, I think permutations and combinations is the way to go for solving this puzzle.

#### Question

There are 4 variables:

```
11
01
10
00
```

I want to know the total number of combinations using the above variables when divided into two categories.

#### Example 1

```
A = 11 - 01
B = 10 - 00
```

The above makes it 1 set of combination. So in total how many variations can be derived?

#### Example 2:

```
A = 01 - 11
B = 10 - 00
```

and so on..

Comment: There are $4P2 = 12$ ways to arrange the number in the first category. Then we have only 1 way to arrange the other two in the next category

Comment: I think you are asking how many ways are there to partition a set with 4 elements.  This type of question is answered by Bell numbers.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions

Comment: Varun.. How can there be 12, when i'm currently seeing more than 15... (Manually doing the combinations in Excel).

Comment: Paw.. thanks for the reference.. i'll try to look around for a simpler version of the bell numbers

Comment: Ok.. Found a simpler version of the bell numbers. But I still think something's missing. Example, if I opt for a Bn of 4, then it gives a total of 15 combinations.. But what about the two sets A and B??

Comment: If the Question is framed as about "partitions", then swapping the roles of categories $A$ and $B$ leaves the solution unchanged.  However if your categories $A$ and $B$ are "labels" (hence distinguishable), then you change the solution by swapping the roles.  It's up to Sledge81 to say which is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your examples 1 and 2, order within groups matters. If so, then  there are $4! = 24$ such ordered partitions. Indeed, they are all generated by ordering the four elements in some way ($4!$ ways to do so) and drawing a line between first two and the last two.

Comment: Thanks.. 24 it is... Based on my excel combinations so far.